# SQL Self Join to work out freight percentage when invoices are stored in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sum

I need to work out the freight percentage value on each shipment the company brings in. The invoices for the freight and the goods are stored in the same table, VSI denotes a goods invoice, VBL denotes a freight invoice, they are joined together via a job cost. I have tried to self join the sets of tables, but the end sum is always multiplied by the amount of matching records. Any help would be appreciated.

Tables

JobCost

```
JobCostID       JobCostDescription   JobCostNumber
4910            ITS-1005104          JBC-1004880
4911            ITS-1005105          JBC-1004881
```

PurchaseInvoice

```
PIID          PINumber    ExchangeRate   VendorId     
1             VSI-1       1              1
2             VSI-2       1              2
3             VBL-1       1              3
```

PurchaseInvoiceItem

```
PIItemID      PIID        Item
1             1           ProductA
2             1           ProductB
3             2           ProductA
4             2           ProductB
5             3           Fuel
6             3           Handling
```

PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail

```
PIItemDetailID    QtyShipped     Cost      PIItemID    JobCostID
1                 2              2500      1           4910
2                 2              2500      2           4910  
3                 2              2500      3           4911
4                 2              2500      4           4911
5                 1              25        5           4910
6                 1              75        6           4910
```

Vendor

```
VendorId    VendorCode    VendorName
1           VEN1          Vendor1
2           VEN2          Vendor2
3           Freight1      Agent1
```

Desired result

```
JobCostID JobCostDescription VendorCode VendorName FreightAgentCode FreightAgentName InvoiceTotal FreightTotal FreightPercentage
4910      ITS-1005104        VEN1       Vendor1    Freight1           Agent1         10000        100          1%     
4920      ITS-1005105        VEN2       Vendor2                                      10000   



   SELECT tblJobCost1.JobCostID, tblJobCost1.JobCostDescription, tblVendor1.VendorCode, tblVendor1.VendorName, tblVendor2.VendorCode AS 'FreightAgentCode', tblVendor2.VendorName AS 'FreightAgentName',  
SUM(PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail1.QtyShipped*PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail1.Cost*PurchaseInvoice1.ExchangeRate) AS 'InvoiceTotal',
SUM(PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2.QtyShipped*PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2.Cost*PurchaseInvoice2.ExchangeRate) AS 'FreightTotal', 
SUM(PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2.QtyShipped*PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2.Cost*PurchaseInvoice2.ExchangeRate)/SUM(PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail1.QtyShipped*PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail1.Cost*PurchaseInvoice1.ExchangeRate)*100 AS 'FreightPercentage'
FROM tblJobCost AS tblJobCost1 
LEFT JOIN tblJobCost AS tblJobCost2 ON tblJobCost1.JobCostID  = tblJobCost2.JobCostID
LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail AS tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail1 ON tblJobCost1.JobCostID = tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail1.JobCostID
LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail AS tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2 ON tblJobCost2.JobCostID = tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2.JobCostID
LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseInvoiceItem AS tblPurchaseInvoiceItem1 ON tblPurchaseInvoiceItem1.PIItemID = tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail1.PIItemID
LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseInvoiceItem AS tblPurchaseInvoiceItem2 ON tblPurchaseInvoiceItem2.PIItemID = tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2.PIItemID
LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseInvoice AS tblPurchaseInvoice1 ON tblPurchaseInvoiceItem1.PIID = tblPurchaseInvoice1.PIID
LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseInvoice AS tblPurchaseInvoice2 ON tblPurchaseInvoiceItem2.PIID = tblPurchaseInvoice2.PIID
LEFT JOIN tblVendor AS tblVendor1 ON tblVendor1.VendorId = tblPurchaseInvoice1.VendorID
LEFT JOIN tblVendor AS tblVendor2 ON tblVendor2.VendorId = tblPurchaseInvoice2.VendorID
WHERE tblPurchaseInvoice1.PINumber LIKE 'VSI%' AND tblPurchaseInvoice2.PINumber LIKE 'VBL%'
GROUP BY tblJobCost1.JobCostID, tblJobCost1.JobCostDescription, tblVendor1.VendorCode, tblVendor1.VendorName, tblVendor2.VendorCode, tblVendor2.VendorName
```

Comment: there is a missing part how do you know  for example PInumber  VBL-1 which is the freight invoice corresponds to VSI-1 ?

Comment: In the table PurchaseInvoiceItemDetail is the job cost id, here you can see VBL-1 and VSI-1 have the same job cost number

Answer (score 0):

Then you are missing a critical condition:

```
...
 LEFT JOIN tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail AS tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2 
        ON tblJobCost2.JobCostID = tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2.JobCostID
        AND tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail1.JobCostID = tblPurchaseInvoiceItemDetail2.JobCostID
...
```